# When does session property (express session data object) gets added to request object when using express-session middleware?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-session

When I use express-session middleware, when does the `session` property in `request` object(`request.session`) gets available?

1. Does it always stay available since the beginning when the server starts? when no session is made (no login) then session data is empty but `session` property itself is always available on `request` object. Is is this case? OR
2. does `session` object gets attached to `request` only when someone logs in? and when no user is logged in then `request.session` is always `undefined` . is it this?

The intention of this question is to know which, in typescript, out of the follow two type definition I have to use:
(one is using `session?` and in another `session` is used)

```
import { SessionData } from "express-session";

declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
  }
}
export interface MyContext {
  session: SessionData;
}
```

OR

```
import { SessionData } from "express-session";

declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
  }
}
export interface MyContext {
  session?: SessionData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After long waiting I got the answer in Ben Awad discord channel.
Here it is

> Session middleware is always defined, if no session exists on the request it'll return an empty object.

So the option-1 type definition is right, i.e.,

```
import { SessionData } from "express-session";

declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    userId: string;
  }
}
export interface MyContext {
  session: SessionData;
}
```